# Updated MediaWiki to version 1.31. Now Spam Blacklist and Title Blacklist are causing errors

Tags: php, mediawiki, wiki

I had (I think) version 1.23 because that's what the auto-installer on my host put there. So I uploaded the files for 1.31 and ran the update.php script. The site seemed to run fine until I tried to save an edit, at which point it gave me this error:

[image]

I disabled all the extensions, which stopped the error, and then re-enabled them one by one, and discovered that the two that caused errors were Spam Blacklist and Title Blacklist. I confirmed that they were the most recent versions, so that isn't the problem. Is anyone aware of this issue?

Comment: Chances are you are using mismatching core and extension versions. Use the same release branch for everything.

Comment: I uploaded the version of Title Blacklist specifically for 1.31 and uncommented the extension, and it promptly had an error. It turns out that the extension folder didn't have any of the PHP files in it. It did have them in the "includes" folder. So I changed the link in LocalSettings. There was no error, but the Version page showed it wasn't even detecting the extension at all. Even copying the PHP files from Includes to the extension root folder (and reverting LocalSettings) didn't help.

Comment: Most extensions these days [need to be registered](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Extension_registration#Migration_for_site_administrators) with `wfLoadExtension`.

Answer (score 1):

You almost definitely had the 1.23 version of `SpamBlacklist.php` lying around in your 1.31 installation, and your `LocalSettings.php` was referring to that still.

That extension was rearranged—and bundled into MediaWiki core—around 1.31, and the directory structure changed. All the source files are now in an `includes` subdirectory.

So you were using the 1.23 version of the `SpamBlacklist` extension, which used  a function, `wfProfileIn`, which the release notes show was removed in 1.31.

I'm sure you've figured out how to fix or work around this by now, more than a year later, but what this means is if you had taken either one of Tgr's suggestions (either start with a fresh MediaWiki installation, or use `wfLoadExtension` to load the new version of SpamBlacklist), you would've arrived at a solution.

This exact problem you had is exactly why I do MediaWiki upgrades between LTS releases by starting with a freshly-extracted tarball from the web site. I get that this isn't your fault, and it likely has more to do with how your hosting provider does automatic upgrades. This will just have to be something you're aware of and look out for in the future!

[image: Screenshot of 'ag' run on both MW 1.23 and 1.31's SpamBlacklist extension code]